# How do I give permissions to another user on firebase?

Tags: firebase, firebase-security

Where can I add an extra user on firebase settings. I cannot find the place to do it. Do I have to set it up using json on the security tab?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

[Engineer at Firebase] I'm happy to report that we've just rolled out support for this feature! Clicking the "Collaborators" link below the name of each of your Firebases will launch a dialog allowing you to invite and manage the list of users that have access to your Firebase.

As the Firebase owner, you can invite and remove other users, use Forge, manage billing, and modify the Firebase plan. Collaborators have access to Forge, but cannot edit or view the list of users on the Firebase, or edit billing / plan information.

We're just getting started with this feature, so let us know if you have any feedback by contacting us at support@firebase.com.

Comment: Please also add the ability to change owners as well.

Comment: I've just added my `@google.com` account to a Firebase created by my personal account, and the `@google.com` account only saw the empty new Firebase, not the one I added myself as a collaborator to. I had to log out and back in to see the shared PWA.

Answer (score 6):

From your [firebase console](http://console.firebase.google.com), click on setting > permissions and in page open click on IAM > +ADD then add member and its role

Comment: Which role to add? There is no Firebase role

Answer (score 2):

You can't currently do this. The Firebase team said they'll be offering this feature in the Forge soon. For now, you can contact them directly from your Firebase account email and ask them to manually add another account to a specific base.

Answer (score 0):

Please find the steps to add:

1. Log in to https://console.firebase.google.com using your Google account. A screen will be displayed with option Add Project.
2. Click on the **Add Project** option. You will be asked to enter App name and country. Then proceed by clicking on **Create Project** button.
3. Click on **Users and Permission** option from **Settings/cog wheel** icon which is adjacent to **Project Overview**, present on the left menu list.
4. You will be redirected to new a webpage(https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/iam) and proceed with accepting the terms.
5. Click on **IAM** option from the left menu list. Add member by selecting **Add** on IAM screen.
6. Provide email id and role, then click on **Add** for adding the member.

Answer (score 0):

Open Firebase console.

Select Project for which you want to share permissions.

On left top side, near Project OverView you will see a setting Icon.

Click on Setting Icon , you will see two Options. Select user's role and permissions.

Add Email ids here.

Done