# Link firebase analytic to Google play

Tags: android, google-analytics, firebase, google-play-services, firebase-analytics

I am trying to link my firebase analytic project to google play, but i have created firebase project with 'x' email id and google play account owner is with different email id so how can i link that.
I get this message in my firebase project:- You are not the owner of a Google Play account. Please create an account or contact an owner to link.

so i just wanted to know is there any method to do this. because my firebase project is already linked up with my app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18838034/1641556)

> [Engineer at Firebase] I'm happy to report that we've just rolled out
>   support for this feature! Clicking the "Collaborators" link below the
>   name of each of your Firebases will launch a dialog allowing you to
>   invite and manage the list of users that have access to your Firebase.
>
> As the Firebase owner, you can invite and remove other users, use
>   Forge, manage billing, and modify the Firebase plan. Collaborators
>   have access to Forge, but cannot edit or view the list of users on the
>   Firebase, or edit billing / plan information.
>
> We're just getting started with this feature, so let us know if you
>   have any feedback by contacting us at support@firebase.com.

Check this also : [Add developer account users & manage permissions](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/2528691?hl=en)

Comment: I already put sha1 key but still getting error like this app failed to link because it is not signed with a production signing certificate SHA1 in Google Play. You can add this SHA1 within the General tab of Project settings.  @devopsEMK

Comment: @MukeshGupta Try with this https://developers.google.com/drive/android/auth#generate_the_signing_certificate_fingerprint_and_register_your_application

Comment: @MukeshGupta check this also http://stackoverflow.com/a/16601346/1641556

Comment: i put again the same sha1 key in firebase project but getting same error. i tried below solution also but getting same error

Comment: and one more thing i already publish the alpha version of the app